# No debugging data in vmlinux when running crash to analyze kernel panic

Tags: crash, linux-kernel, opensuse

I'm trying to analyze a Linux kernel panic on openSUSE 11.3 using kdump and the crash utility. The system is successfully creating the vmcore file, but when I go to analyze it, crash complains about the lack of symbols.

```
# crash -s vmlinux-2.6.34-12-desktop.gz vmcore
crash: vmlinux-2.6.34-12-desktop.gz: no debugging data available
crash: vmlinux-2.6.34-12-desktop.debug: debuginfo file not found

crash: either install the appropriate kernel debuginfo package, or
       copy vmlinux-2.6.34-12-desktop.debug to this machine
```

The system is running a stock desktop kernel

```
# uname -r
2.6.34-12-desktop
```

and has the `kernel-devel` and `kernel-desktop-devel` packages installed. Does some other package have the debug symbols (similar to Red Hat's kernel-debuginfo rpm) or is there another approach / kernel I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbols for openSUSE are named similarly to Red Hat and variants (CentOS, Fedora, ...) but live in a different [repository](http://download.opensuse.org/debug/). For this example, the vmlinux symbols are in the `kernel-desktop-devel-debuginfo` package, but practically, you'd probably also want to grab the `kernel-desktop-debuginfo` for the module symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Load the "kernel-debug-devel" package for your kernel.

Comment: The system has all the kernel-*-devel packages installed including debug, but do you mean I need to be running the debug kernel (`/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.34.7-0.5-debug`) as well?

Comment: You said you were running "2.6.34-12" - the debug kernel listed was "2.6.34.7-0.5". So if you only have debug symbols for that kernel - you need to run it - *but* make sure you have modules for it installed too.

Comment: My apologies, 2.6.34.7-0.5 was a cut-n-paste error; everything is in fact 2.6.34-12. I installed the debug kernel, but pointing crash at `/boot/vmlinux-2.6.34-12-debug.gz` gives the same "no debugging data available" error.